# Asignar a un usuario unos datos despues de registrarse

Tags: php, laravel

quiero que nada mas registrarse un usuario obtener de la tabla jugadores, todos los jugadores que tengan el campo id_user vacio y de esoss obtener aleatoriamente unos 15, para asignarles en el campo id_user, la ID del usuario que se acaba de registrar.
No se en que parte debo de implementar el codigo para que nada mas registrarse el usuario se ejecute.

Comment: Publicá el código de lo que tenés hasta ahora. Por lo menos los modelos de tus tablas.

Answer (score 0):

despues que apliques el $user->save() en el usuario deberias hacer:

obtener aleatoriamente 15 jugadores con id_user vacio:

```
$jugadores = table('jugadores')->inRandomOrder()
->whereNull('id_user')
->limit(15)
->get();
```

luego haces el update:

```
$jugadores->update(['id_user' => $user->id]);
```

o lo puedes hacer con el attach